# Criando um classe customizada do tipo WritableComparator

Tags: java, classificação, hadoop

Estou criando uma aplicação para processar vídeo de maneira distribuída no hadoop utilizando o paradigma *map-reduce*. Eu tenho vários vídeos armazenados no cluster e desejo a partir deles criar um único arquivo de vídeo.

Para isso, eu estou extraindo os frames de cada vídeo na fase *map* e os envio para a fase *reduce*. Cada vídeo é numerado de 1 a 9, e o início da chave de cada frame corresponde ao vídeo que a originou, por exemplo a chave 11788847 corresponde a um frame do vídeo 1, por outro lado a chave 57845 corresponde ao vídeo de número 5. Repare que mesmo a chave 11788847 sendo maior que a chave 57845, ela deve vir antes para que os frames sejam agrupados de acordo com o vídeo.

Para isso, eu implementei a classe `SortingCustomComparator` que herda de `WiritableComparator`. Segue o código abaixo:

```
public class SortingCustomComparator extends WritableComparator{

protected SortingCustomComparator(){
    super(Text.class, true);
}
@Override
public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2){
    // Converte a string em um inteiro
    String key1 = null;
    String key2 = null;
    try {
        key1 = Text.decode(b1, s1, l1);
        key2 = Text.decode(b2, s2, l2);
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    int keyInt = Integer.valueOf(key1.trim());
    int key2Int = Integer.valueOf(key2.trim());
    return (keyInt >key2Int) ? 1 : -1;

}  }
```

O problema é que o código acima não tem o comportamento esperado. O vídeo criado contém alguns frames que são colocados em posição aleatória. Eu gostaria que as chaves fosse agrupadas por blocos. As chaves do primeiro vídeo devem estar ordenadas em ordem crescente e devem pertencer ao conjunto do primeiro vídeo assim como a do segundo pertencer ao do segundo e assim sucessivamente. Ex.: {11, 12, 13, 14, ..., 111, 112}, {2, 21, 22, ...}. Ao final estes blocos de chaves devem ser ordenados {11, 12, 13, 14, ..., 2, 21, 22}. Assim os frames ficarão agrupados na ordem correta o vídeo não ficará bugado. Alguém saberia como implementar isso corretamente?

Desde já eu agradeço.

Comment: Achei essa forma de ordenação bem ruim. Você não tem como escolher uma outra melhor?

Comment: O problema é que as chaves correspondem aos frames em sua ordem correta. Cada frame do vídeo um inicia com 1, o do vídeo dois com 2 e assim sucessivamente. Todas os frames do vídeo 1 devem vir antes dos frames do vídeo 2 senão a recomposição do vídeo fica ruim com vários frames em posições aleatórias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

1 - Cada vídeo começa com um número que corresponde ao seu vídeo de origem;
2 - O número de origem é concatenado com o número do frame que é gerado na aplicação;
3 - Criei uma classe personalizada que efetua a comparação conforme o código abaixo:

```
public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2){
    /*
     * Converte a string em um inteiro
     */ 
    String key1 = null;
    String key2 = null;
    try {
        key1 = Text.decode(b1, s1, l1);
        key2 = Text.decode(b2, s2, l2);
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    int keyInt = Integer.valueOf(key1.trim());
    int key2Int = Integer.valueOf(key2.trim());

    String strKey1 = Integer.toString(keyInt);
    String strKey2 = Integer.toString(key2Int);

    int keyFirstP1 = Integer.parseInt(strKey1.substring(0, 1));
    int key2FirstP1 = Integer.parseInt(strKey2.substring(0, 1));

    strKey1 = modifieString(strKey1);
    strKey2 = modifieString(strKey2);


    //return cmp.compare(strKey1, strKey2);

    if(keyFirstP1 == key2FirstP1){
            return (keyInt > key2Int) ? 1 : -1; 
    }

    if(keyFirstP1 != key2FirstP1){
         return (keyFirstP1 > key2FirstP1) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
```

Primeiro comparamos o primeiro elemento de cada uma das chaves. Se eles forem iguais a chave é comparada por inteiro, caso contrário só retornamos a comparação entre o primeiro elemento de cada chave, garantindo assim a correta ordem dos frames.

Answer (score 1):

Tente trocar isso:

```
int keyInt = Integer.valueOf(key1.trim());
int key2Int = Integer.valueOf(key2.trim());
return (keyInt >key2Int) ? 1 : -1;
```

Por isso:

```
return key1.compareTo(key2);
```

Comment: A presente solução não resolve o meu problema. O que eu desejo é por subconjunto. Tipo se eu tenho as chaves 1,2,4,11, 17, 22 elas deveriam ser ordenadas da seguinte forma 1,11,17, 2,22, 4.